# ngCordova - Get network name

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I need for my app, to get the wifi's exact network name. With this name, the app will generate a set of results completely diferent of the results generated outside this network.

I need a solution for both Android and iOS.

At Cordova's docs I can't find any alternative for this.

Any advice ?

Comment: there is a plugin for that but its not listed in ngCordova list https://github.com/hoerresb/WifiWizard

Comment: Hi, I saw it some time ago...there's a restriction for iOS : "iOS has limited functionality, as Apple's WifiManager equivalent is only available as a private API. Any app that used these features would not be allowed on the app store..."

Comment: yes but it says that "The only function availabe for iOS is getCurrentSSID"

Comment: isnt it he SSID that you need?

Comment: I'll try it Akis. Have you experienced it ?

Comment: nope but i know from other people. give it a try and use the `WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(ssidHandler, fail);` method

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.